# Prolog ERROR: is/2

Tags: prolog

If I try

```
logPower(X, N, REZ) :-
    N mod 2 =:= 0,
    !,
    N1 is N/2,
    logPower(X, N1, REZ1), 
    REZ is REZ1*REZ.
```

it doesn't work and I get

`ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`

but instead if I try

```
logPower(X, N, REZ) :- 
    N mod 2 =:= 0,
    !, 
    N1 is N-1, 
    logPower(X, N1, REZ1), 
    REZ is REZ1*REZ.
```

it works.

How may I edit the first one to work ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproduceable working example. Currently it is guesswork in which context you get this error.

Comment: Oh, soorry. `logPower(X, N, REZ):- N mod 2 =:= 0,!, N1 is N/2, logPower(X,N1,REZ1), REZ is REZ1*REZ.`

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting bits and pieces in comments.

Comment: I've added the entire code now :)

Comment: There error occurs because `is/2` requires that **all** variables on the right hand side be instantiated. So the `REZ is REZ1 * REZ` will fail, always unless (1) `REZ` and `REZ1` both already have a value, and (2) `REZ1` has the value of 1 (since otherwise it could never be true that `REZ` is the same value as `REZ1 * REZ`.

Comment: Thanks! That was it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer has already been given [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34705190/prolog-error-is-2#comment57165645_34705190), but I'll expand it a little to explain exactly what's going on.

The problem lies in the line `REZ is REZ1*REZ`. The predicate `is/2` needs to have all arguments on the right hand side to be instantiated, like the error message tells you. But you're trying to use `REZ` as a variable, *which it isn't*.

Now I'm assuming you have another clause that servers as a stopping point (or starting point, depending how you look at it) for `logPower/3`, or otherwise you would have an infinite loop, but the question remains, why does the first version produce an error but not the second one, since they both contain the same line `REZ is REZ1*REZ`?

Well, your second version replaced the line `N1 is N/2` with `N1 is N-1`, after which you "call" `logPower/3` again. You checked if `N` is even, then you either divided by 2 or subtracted 1. In the former case, if `N` was dividable by *4*, `N1` will still be even, giving you a chance to hit the starting point for `logPower/3` and reach the line with the problem.
But in the latter case, `N1` will not be even and you will fail, without hitting the error, except for an `N` that will make you hit the starting point before failing because of the even/odd-check.